# Getting Image Data from Database as cv::Mat format using C++ and Ado

Tags: c++, database, opencv, ado.net, ado

I'm tring to read image from MS-SQL Database using ADO (C++). The Images are stored as varBinary(max) in Database. I tried to  get and convert images to **`cv::Mat`** format.

Here is the code i have,

```
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    
    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConnection;
    hr = pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection));
    pConnection->CursorLocation = ADODB::adUseClient;

    hr=pConnection->Open(L"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SAMPLE-DB;"
    L"Initial Catalog=IMAGE;User Id=sr;Password=****;", L"", 
     L"", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
       //error handling...
    }

    ADODB::_RecordsetPtr recordset;
    hr = recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset));

    std::string cmd = "SQL COMMAND THAT PROVIDE IMAGE BINARY";

    recordset->Open(cmd.c_str(), pConnection.GetInterfacePtr(),
    
    ADODB::adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adCmdText);
    
    std::vector<uchar> buffer;
    buffer = recordset->Fields->GetItem(L"ImgBinary")->GetValue(); //problem!!
        
   cv::Mat testImage = cv::imdecode(buffer,cv::IMREAD_COLOR); //problem!!

   cv::namedWindow("MyWindow");
   cv::imshow("MyWindow",testImage);
```

Errors I got,

> > 1-) 'cv::imdecode' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

> > 2-) IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "_variant_t" to
> > "std::vector<uchar, std::allocator>" exists

Could you please help? How can i get image as **`cv::Mat`** format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! The problem was  `GetValue()` method. We need to use `GetChunk()` method because we get an array from database. `GetChunk()` has to have a size parameter. We can get size with,

```
long lngSize = recordset->Fields->GetItem(L"ImgBinary")->ActualSize;
```

code line.

The edited version of code is below,

```
HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConnection;
hr = pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection));
pConnection->CursorLocation = ADODB::adUseClient;

hr=pConnection->Open(L"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SAMPLE-DB;"
L"Initial Catalog=IMAGE;User Id=sr;Password=****;", L"", 
 L"", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
   //error handling...
}

ADODB::_RecordsetPtr recordset;
hr = recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset));

std::string cmd = "SQL COMMAND THAT PROVIDE IMAGE BINARY";

recordset->Open(cmd.c_str(), pConnection.GetInterfacePtr(),

ADODB::adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB::adLockReadOnly, ADODB::adCmdText);

/////////////// Edited Part ///////////////

long lngSize = recordset->Fields->GetItem(L"ImgBinary")->ActualSize;  

_variant_t varChunk = recordset->Fields->GetItem(L"ImgBinary")->GetChunk(lngSize);

    std::vector<uchar> buffer(lngSize); 
    SAFEARRAY* pData=NULL;
    pData=V_ARRAY(&varChunk);

    void *pVoid = 0;
    hr = ::SafeArrayAccessData(pData, &pVoid);
    uchar *pBinary = reinterpret_cast<uchar *>(pVoid);

       for (int i = 0; i < pData->rgsabound[0].cElements; ++i)
        { 
          buffer[i] = pBinary[i];
        }

      hr = ::SafeArrayUnaccessData(pData);
      cv::Mat testImage = cv::imdecode(buffer,cv::IMREAD_COLOR); 
      cv::namedWindow("MyWindow");
      cv::imshow("MyWindow",testImage); 
      cv::waitKey();
```